# Get full line with fscanf function

Tags: php, stdint

I have to read a full line from stdin. When I use `fscanf` it reads only string before a space. I need to read a whole line inluding spaces. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Comment: [Documentation for `fscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php). Use the scroll wheel and go down to the section called *See Also*. Read it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$line = fgets();
```

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgets.php) says:

> Description
>
> string fgets ( resource $handle [, int $length ] )
>
> Gets a line from file pointer.